# What, if any, effect does the Martian magnetic field have on dust storms?

Tags: mars, magnetic-field, dust, dust-storm

Since we know most dust particles on Mars are [magnetic](https://physicsworld.com/a/rover-reveals-magnetic-mars/), I was wondering if they might be affected by the Martian magnetic field.

Can the Martian magnetic field have any effect on the spatial distribution of a Martian dust storm?

Comment: Close voter: Please be aware that planetary science *is* on topic on Space Exploration: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/58

Answer (score 3):

We would not expect much of an effect when the strongest Martian magnetic field is [only about 2% of Earth's](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2008/1710.html).  Mars does not have a global dynamo like Earth, the Martian dynamo having long since collapsed; its field comes from extrinsic sources such as the solar wind or, perchance, those storm-driven dust particles.  In numerical terms, quoting from the source above, is a maximum of 1500 nT on Mars vs 65,000 nT on our big blue marble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i exactly wanted to know is there any co relation between  magnetic anomaly and spatial distribution of dust storm in Mars?

Comment: @jyotirmoy I think Oscar's implying that the influence of the magnetic field(s) on the dust particles would be negligible, thus there wouldn't be a correlation. Of course, this is inference, not evidence, so you don't have to accept the reasoning.